# Spring SimpleFormController onSubmit request parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using `SimpleFormController` in my application to handle form submisions. one thing i am missing is the request object that is passed `onSubmit(request,response..)` 
is a different one from the initial request object that is received by `formBackingObject(..)`.probably because it is again a new request from web.

i just want to use the same parameters from request object in `onSubmit(..)` that i was able to access in `formBackingObject(..)`.

it could be possible for me to store them in and pass thru hidden fields from jsp, but i am trying to get some elegant approach.

is there any way to achieve this?

EDIT:

i am overriding

```
formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request)`
```

and

```
onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors)
```

methods in my class.

for the intial view `formbackingObject(..)`  will be called and i will have some variables from the request object then if user submits the form `onSubmit(..)` will be called then i will have another request object which is different from the one i received in `formbackingObject(..)` .

what i am asking is, is there any way of holding the
initial 'request'
parameters(`request.getParameter()` kind
of...) so that i can use them in
`onSubmit(..)` with out sending them
back & forth thru hidden fields ?'

Comment: he's using spring MVC. 
@sangram - give more details - what submits are happening, when, what are your pages, etc.

Comment: edited. i want to use the parameters strings in onSubmit() that i have received when formBacking() is called.i have the request objects in both formbacking & onsubmit. but they are different (get&post) . i am just checking if there is a simpler way to hold back the initial request's parameter strings instead of sending them again back to onSubmit() with hidden fields.

Comment: What is the scope of the data returned by `formBackingObject`? is it common to all users, common to the session, what?

Comment: Does this sound like a case for spring web flow? You could hold it is session as Shane suggests or you could put the values from the first request into the model on the GET and pass it back in on the POST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `formBackingObject()` method is being called when the user makes the request for the initial form view. This is a completely separate HTTP request to when the user submits the form which is when the `onSubmit()` method is called.

If you want to save state from the first HTTP request so it is available in the second HTTP request, your best option is probably to save it in the HTTP session.

eg: in your `formBackingObject()` method:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("param1", request.getParameter("param1"));
session.setAttribute("param2", request.getParameter("param2"));
```

and in your `onSubmit()` method:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String param1 = (String) session.getAttribute("param1");
String param2 = (String) session.getAttribute("param2");
```

Comment: Thanks Shane ! probably that's the only way as it is a completely new HTTP request.

Answer (score 2):

`formBackingObject()` is expected to set up the "command" Object that is supplied to `onSubmit()` on the next submission. The command Object is just a [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) that you can create and add attributes to as needed.

Normally you populate the command Object with some data to be displayed on the screen from a service call (which ultimately comes from the DB) but there's nothing to stop you placing data that arrived in the request in `formBackingObject()` into the command Object and pulling it back off again when `onSubmit()` is called. The advantage of doing this is that you don't end up with [cruft](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cruft) floating around in your session.

For example, put a boolean from the request in `MyCommand` in `formBackingObject()`:

```
    protected Object formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        boolean someBoolean = ServletRequestUtils.getBooleanParameter(request, "someBoolean");
        MyCommand myCommand = new MyCommand();
        myCommand.setSomeBoolean(someBoolean);
        // optionally get some data from the DB to set on myCommand here...
        return myCommand;
    }
```

Then find that boolean inside the request in `onSubmit()`:

```
    protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors)
    {
        MyCommand myCommand = (MyCommand) command;
        if (myCommand.getSomeBoolean()) {
            System.out.println("someBoolean was set in formBackingObject!");
        }
    }
```

Note that myCommand is only visible to the session (so no other logged in users can see it, and it is destroyed when the session ends).